# Visual Studio 2022: Failed to sign No certificates were found that met all given criteria

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10, exe, signtool

I have a legacy program that I'm making simple updates to. I'm running a build from Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10 by pressing the `Start` button and I'm getting the error

`An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\x86\Debug\app.publish\Data Review Utility.exe. SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.`

What I have done:

- The older certificate was expired so I created a new Test Certificate with no password
- I made sure that the certificate is installed.
- The certificate is in
  the Trused Root Certification Authorities for the Current User.
- The certificate Thumbprint matches the value in the .csproj.
- I have run Visual Studio both regularly and as admin.
- The Intended Purposes is All

If I open the Developer PowerShell and run this command:

```
signtool sign /debug /f "C:\LocalFiles\ReportTool\Data_Review_Utility\Data Review Utility.pfx" "C:\LocalFiles\ReportTool\Data_Review_Utility\bin\x86\Debug\app.publish\Data Review Utility.exe"
```

Then I get the following:

```
The following certificates were considered:
    Issued to: akirk
    Issued by: akirk
    Expires:   Thu Jun 27 13:21:56 2024
    SHA1 hash: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1

After EKU filter, 1 certs were left.
After expiry filter, 1 certs were left.
After Private Key filter, 1 certs were left.
The following certificate was selected:
    Issued to: akirk
    Issued by: akirk
    Expires:   Thu Jun 27 13:21:56 2024
    SHA1 hash: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX1


The following additional certificates will be attached:
Done Adding Additional Store
Successfully signed: C:\LocalFiles\ReportTool\Data_Review_Utility\bin\x86\Debug\app.publish\Data Review Utility.exe

Number of files successfully Signed: 1
Number of warnings: 0
Number of errors: 0
```

So it works when running signtool from the command line, but I get the error when pressing the `Start` button.  I do not want to uncheck `Sign the ClickOnce manifests` or change the targeted framework because my updates need to be only those that are fixing bugs. What am I missing?

Comment: VS 2022 might be trying to use SHA-256?  If your cert only supports SHA-1 then that will fail.

Comment: And how is this rectified?

Comment: If my guess is right (but it is just a guess): (a) change the sign step in VS2022 or (b) generate a cert with SHA-256 support.   SHA-1 is considered too weak to be safe now so SHA-256 is better option.  I don't sign in VS2022 I have a separate script file  so I can't say how to change your build step.

Comment: There is no sign step when running from the Start button. When Creating a Test Certificate, there is not option to choose SHA-256.  It only generates an SHA1 certificate.

Answer (score 1):

According to Dave S's idea, you need to generate a certificate that supports SHA-256. But you find that there is no option for SHA-256. This is because this is an old project. You need to right-click the project in the project explorer, then click project properties, and change the target framework of the project to a version above .net framework4.0. This way the SHA-256 can be chosen

[image]

[image]

Comment: As stated in the original post, I cannot make any changes other than fixing the bugs. I definitely cannot change the target framework. However, this raises an idea: maybe I can use an older version of Visual Studio to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @AlexaKirk If my answer is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people. Does an older version of Visual Studio solve your issue?