# Code signing ClickOnce manifest in Visual Studio 2022 after June 2023 with a USB token

Tags: c#, visual-studio, manifest, clickonce, code-signing

I am going mental in trying to find a solution to sign a ClickOnce manifest of a simple desktop app in Visual Studio 2022. I have a new standard code signing certificate issued after June 2023 (i.e., USB token).
Every time I click on "Publish" and then select "Sign the ClickOnce Manifest" and "Select from Store", I get the error "No Certificates Were Found That Met All the Given Criteria".

Any idea why? Or, is there any workaround/different process I can follow to sign the manifest?

I tried signing different manifests from different apps and I am getting the same error. Signing code using SignTool works without problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76583807/visual-studio-2022-failed-to-sign-no-certificates-were-found-that-met-all-given

Comment: @HansPassant thank you. My certificate does support SHA-256 though and the project I want to sign uses the latest NET Framework version. hmm...I will try installing Visual Studio 2019 to see if it fixes the error however, I doubt it.

Comment: @Andy Hi, can you solve this issue after installing Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT. Hi, I have just tried and I am getting the same error message :-/ Any suggestion?

Comment: @Andy Hi, I posted an answer. If it was helpful to you, please mark it (click the check mark to the left of the answer) so that it can help more people. If it doesn't work for you please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .net framework:

Project properties=>signing=>Create Test Certificate

[image]

If this doesn't work for you, you can refer to: [Signtool error: No certificates were found that met all given criteria with a Windows Store App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946399/signtool-error-no-certificates-were-found-that-met-all-given-criteria-with-a-wi)

Comment: The solution you suggested is OK and it does work for those who want to sign the manifest with a test certificate which won't be trusted by major OS. In my case, I need to sign the manifest with a standard CA issued certificate to get rid of Windows warnings so it doesn't help me, I'm afraid. Thanks for trying anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem after my certificate expired, last year. As I understand, from June 2023, the code signing requires more stringent procedure than before and that the most CA's opted for an USB-token based solution. I decided to start using Certum certificates that are much cheaper (120 Euro) and do not require a physical token. Instead, signing works with a phone app and the local certificate store. From the users perspective it appears working from the certificate store. I have no idea how their solution actually works, but it works just fine (I'm signing my C# desktop application directly from Visual Studio 2022)